# function is not accessed by pylance

Tags: python

Keep getting this error on `GameStats`. The module it's in is in same directory as the rest but it just won't see it. I've restarted Vscode and get same message. Driving me nuts. runing Win11

```py
from time import sleep

# Error here
from stats import GameStats

from settings import Settings

from ship import Ship

from bullet import Bullet

from alien import Alien

from button import Button

Windows PowerShell
    ai.run_game()
  File "c:\Users\jerry\Desktop\learningpython\alieninvasion.py", line 42, in run_game
    if self.stats.game_active:
AttributeError: 'AlienInvasion' object has no attribute 'stats'
PS C:\Users\jerry\Desktop\learningpython>
```

Comment: what is your os system?

Comment: Can you post the full error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Function in module finally became seen when I instantiated it in the **ini**. I didn't know that was necessary for import statements to not show an error like I was getting.